# How to Print treemap in reverse order

Tags: java, treemap

In my assignment we are read from a file the text:

> To be, or not to be: that is the question:
>    Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer

then count the times each has occured. I've been able to print this map unsorted, then I was able to make a TreeMap and print it in natural order (which is shown below). I don't know how to print in reverse order. I know a way to use a comparator, but I'm a little rusty so I've done what I can. Furthermore, I don't know how to set the comparator up to sort the Treemap into reverse order.

Here's my method to print Unsorted and Naturally sorted:

```
private static void sortPrintFrequencies(Map<String,Integer> vocabulary, PrintStream                                                  output {
Iterator iterator = vocabulary.keySet().iterator();
System.out.println("Unsorted");

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
 String key = iterator.next().toString();
 String value = vocabulary.get(key).toString();
 String times = "times.";
 String appears = "appears";

System.out.printf("%35s", key + "    " + appears + "    " + value + " "+ times);
System.out.println();
    }
System.out.println("========================================");
System.out.println("SORTED NATURALLY BY KEY");
TreeMap newVocabulary = new TreeMap(vocabulary);
Iterator iterator2 = newVocabulary.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
  String key = iterator2.next().toString();
  String value = newVocabulary.get(key).toString();
  String times = "times.";
  String appears = "appears";

    System.out.printf("%35s", key + "    " + appears + "    " + value + " "+ times);
    System.out.println();
}
  TreeMap revVocabulary = new TreeMap(new RevCmpKey());

  System.out.println("========================================");

}
```

Here's my comparator:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RevCmpKey implements Comparator<String> {
public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
    //compareTo in String classs
    if(e1.compareTo(e2) <1)return -1;
    if(e1.compareTo(e2) >1)return 1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: So is your question how to set up a comparator?

Comment: no, actually I was hoping for someone to not only help me with my comparator, but to use to sort the TreeMap. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should show some more effort then. This seems a bit too "give me teh codez" at the moment. Maybe show what you think the comparator should look like, besides the skeleton you have?

Comment: oops!! that's my old comparator code!! ill change it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 65):

What about copying your Map into a new one naturally reverse ordered?

```
new TreeMap<String,Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: `descendingMap` is probably faster (see other answer about this), since it doesn't require copying the entire collection.

Answer (score 22):

## Short Answer:

Use [descendingKeySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingKeySet--) or [descendingMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap--).

## Long Answer:

#### Solution 1:

As Oliver correctly [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14871883/5136131), you can copy the map into a new TreeMap to reach your goal.

However, when using `descendingKeySet`, you won't need to create a new TreeMap:

```
treeMap.descendingKeySet()
```

Here's an example:

```
private static void printReverseTreeMap(TreeMap<String,Integer> treeMap){
    for(String key : treeMap.descendingKeySet()){
        System.out.println("value of " + key + " is " + treeMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2:

You can also create a new Map in reverse order using `descendingMap` as well as `Collections.reverseOrder()`:

```
NavigableMap<String, Integer> reveresedTreeMap = treeMap.descendingMap();
```

Note that `descendingMap` returns `NavigableMap`.

Comment: `NavigableMap.descendingMap()` is probably faster than `Collections.reverseOrder()`, and also probably requires less memory, since a descending map is just a reversed view of the underlying map.

Comment: What's the time complexity (big O) of map.descendingMap()? Can we use this to iterate over the k greatest keys in O(k) time?

Answer (score 1):

Since String is already comparable, the inverse Comparator is trivial:

```
public class RevCmpKey implements Comparator<String> {

  public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
    return - e1.compareTo(e2);
  }
}
```

The other problem is that you are not specifying the values for the Generics; When you construct the TreeMap, you should use

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> revVocabulary = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new RevCmpKey());
```

Then you just call putAll and that is enough

Answer (score 1):

Here you can also prepare a ReverseComparator and use for any class, used in Ordered-Collection :

```
class ReverseComparator implements Comparator<Comparable<Object>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Comparable<Object> o1, Comparable<Object> o2) {

        return o2.compareTo( o1 );
    }

}
```

As usually we compare o1 with o2, but for reverse compare o2 with o1

Answer (score 1):

Just try below

```
private TreeMap<BigInteger, List<TicketingDocumentServiceCouponHistory>> getCpnHistoryMap(
        List<TicketingDocumentHistory> tktHistoryList,List<TicketingDocumentServiceCouponTicket> couponList){

    TreeMap<BigInteger, List<TicketingDocumentServiceCouponHistory>> cpnHistoryMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    cpnHistoryMap.put(BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE), getOcCpnHistoryList(couponList));
    tktHistoryList
            .stream()
            .filter(history -> history.getCode().equals(RVL))
            .forEach(history -> cpnHistoryMap.put(history.getSequence(), getCpnHistoryList(cpnHistoryMap, history)));

    TreeMap<BigInteger, List<TicketingDocumentServiceCouponHistory>> cpnHistMapInOrder =  new TreeMap<>();
    cpnHistMapInOrder.putAll(cpnHistoryMap);
    return cpnHistMapInOrder;
}
```